# How To push array elements from one array to another array

Tags: php, arrays, function

Hello people here is the code that i was using initially....

```
array_push($Parameter_IdArray, $Parameter_Id1, $Parameter_Id2, $Parameter_Id3, $OptParameter_Id);

array_push($Eqt_ParamArray, $eqt_param1, $eqt_param2, $eqt_param3, $Opt_eqt_param1);
```

i had no issues to push array values .... but now `$eqt_param1, $eqt_param2, $eqt_param3 and $Opt_eqt_param1` are in one more array  it is something like this

```
Array ( [Profile_Id] => 4 [eqt_param] => Array ( [0] => 4.00 [1] => 4.00 [2] => 4.00 ) [Parameter_Id1] => 8 [min_param] => Array ( [0] => 1.00 [1] => 1.00 [2] => 1.00 ) [max_param] => Array ( [0] => 5.00 [1] => 5.00 [2] => 5.00 ) [Wtg_param] => Array ( [0] => 25.00 [1] => 25.00 [2] => 50.00 ) [Parameter_Id2] => 5 [Parameter_Id3] => 1 [Opt_eqt_param] => Array ( [0] => 0.00 ) [OptParameter_Id] => 14 [Opt_wtg] => Array ( [0] => 1.05 ) [operator] => Array ( [0] => M ) [eqt_pay] => 1,574,235 [rec_sal] => 1,485,000 [#] => -6.01 % [Emp_Id] => 490699 [Emp_Process] => Confirm New Pay )
```

now i need tp push array values `$eqt_param1`, `$eqt_param2`, `$eqt_param3` and `$Opt_eqt_param1` to `$Eqt_ParamArray` how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've now got an associative array in PHP.  On that assumption, I went ahead and reformatted the nightmare for you:

```
$myarray = array(
  "Profile_Id" => 4,
  "eqt_param" => array(4.00, 4.00, 4.00),
  "Parameter_Id1" => 8,
  "min_param" => array (1.00, 1.00, 1.00 ),
  "max_param" => array (5.00, 5.00, 5.00 ),
  "Wtg_param" => array (25.00, 25.00, 50.00 ),
  "Parameter_Id2" => 5,
  "Parameter_Id3" => 1,
  "Opt_eqt_param" => array (0.00),
  "OptParameter_Id" => 14,
  "Opt_wtg" => array (1.05),
  "operator" => array ("M"),
  "eqt_pay" => array(1,574,235),
  "rec_sal" => array(1,485,000),
  "#" => "-6.01 %",
  "Emp_Id" => 490699,
  "Emp_Process" => "Confirm New Pay"
);
```

What this good formatting now makes clear is that you can use `array_push` directly on the `"eqt_param"` index:

```
array_push($myArray["eqt_param"], $eqt_param1, $eqt_param2, $eqt_param3, $Opt_eqt_param1);
```

You may also mean that you want to replace it, which is easy too:

```
$myArray['eqt_param'] = array($eqt_param1, $eqt_param2, $eqt_param3, $Opt_eqt_param1);
```

The same principles apply in Javascript, which you <s>have</s> had tagged so maybe you mean that.

Comment: Glad to help. Just out of curiousity, why did you call me dear? I see a lot of non-native speakers doing that and I don't fully understand why that is happening...is it because of when people write letters, like Dear Steve, maybe? It sounds sort of strange :)

Comment: hmm please dont mind, Who ever helps me i call them `Dear`, anyways iam sorry if u have felt bad.